# Trying to create a function that counts 3 amounts of lines (lines that aren't empty, lines that are comments, total lines) and return all 3 values

Tags: c

I as the title says I am trying to create a function that will return 3 values when reading a document for an assignment. I wanted to make it work in a function, so I can just call that function and it will output the 3 values, but at the moment the Developer prompt is just running endlessly and not printing anything. Below is a snippet of my code if anybody could help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE 1000

void countLines(int *emptyLines, int *totalLines, int *totalComments)
{
    char line[LINE];
    *emptyLines = 0;
    *totalLines = 0;
    *totalComments = 0;
    FILE *input = fopen("student.java", "r");

    while (fgets(line, LINE, input)) {
        int i;
        int len = strlen(line);
        char *delimiters = "   . , \n \t";
        char *token = strtok(line, delimiters);

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != ' ') {
                emptyLines++;
                break;
            }
        } // counts all the lines that aren't empty
            
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(token, "/**") == 0) {
                totalComments++;
            }
        } // counts the total amount of comments
            
        totalLines++; // counts the total amount of lines
    }
    fclose(input);  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *input = fopen("student.java", "r");
    int emptyLines, totalLines, totalComments;
    
    countLines(&emptyLines, &totalLines, &totalComments);

    printf("There are %d total lines, %d lines of code and %d comments in the file\n",
           totalLines, emptyLines, totalComments);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you open the file twice (once in `main()`, once in `countLines()`) ... and only close it once?

Comment: your `while(token != NULL)` loop does not change `token` inside... so it's either always *true* (infinite loop) or always *false* (no-run loop)

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your code in here `while(token != NULL)`

Comment: How do you expect `while(token != NULL)` to terminate?

Comment: You dont actually need that under while statement. The inside`if` is enough

Comment: Ah okay, I managed to get it printing but now it is just printing 0 for all the values

Comment: Thank you, I was being stupid, thank you for pointing out that the while(token != NULL) does not terminate, i managed to figure it out. Thank you all.

Comment: What happens when you run your program after `chmod -r student.java`?  You should handle errors gracefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has problems:

- `emptyLines++;` does not increment the counter, it increments the pointer, which has no effect on the variable in the `main` function and makes it to an undefined location. Use `*emptyLines += 1;` instead. The same applies to the other counters.
- the loop to detect empty lines actually detect non-empty lines. Calling it after breaking the first token from the line with `strtok()` does not do what you expect. `strtok()` is tricky and should probably not be used for this problems.
- the loop `while (token != NULL)` runs forever if `token` is not `NULL`, ie: if there is at least one nonspace character in the line, because you do not modify `token` in the body of the `while` loop.

First let's be more precise with the goal:

- lines that start with white space followed by `//` are comment lines
- lines that start with white space followed by `/*` are comment lines and the comment extends to the line that contains `*/`
- lines that have just white space are *empty* lines.
- other lines are lines of code.

`strtok()` is not the best function for your purpose: `strspn()` is your friend.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE 1000

void countLines(int *linesOfCode, int *totalLines, int *totalComments) {
    char line[LINE];
    int incomment = 0;
    int skip;
    FILE *input;

    *linesOfCode = 0;
    *totalLines = 0;
    *totalComments = 0;

    if ((input = fopen("student.java", "r")) == NULL)
        return;

    while (fgets(line, LINE, input)) {
        *totalLines += 1;
        // compute the number of white space characters at the beginning of the line
        skip = strspn(line, " \t\f\v\r\n");
        if (incomment) {
            *totalComments += 1;
            if (strstr(line, "*/"))
                incomment = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (line[skip] == '/' && line[skip + 1] == '/') {
            *totalComments += 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (line[skip] == '/' && line[skip + 1] == '*') {
            *totalComments += 1;
            if (!strstr(line, "*/"))
                incomment = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (line[skip] != '\0') {
            *linesOfCode += 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(input);  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int linesOfCode, totalLines, totalComments;
    
    countLines(&linesOfCode, &totalLines, &totalComments);

    printf("There are %d total lines, %d lines of code and %d comment lines in the file\n",
           totalLines, linesOfCode, totalComments);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this method is too simplistic to handle comments that start on a line of code and extend beyond the current line. Detecting such comments is non-trivial, even for the java language because you need to recognise strings and character constants to handle `"/*"` correctly.

To try and get a count of *lines of code* that is independent of the coding style and placement of braces, I would recommend not counting the lines that only contain punctuation such as braces and parentheses. You can simply change the skip line to:

```
   skip = strspn(line, " \t\f\v\r\n{}[]().,:?;");
```

Comment: Nice.  (the usual `isspace()` characters include `'\v'` -- `'\v'` gets [no respect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCVR_ajL_Eo))

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I should try these [vertical tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vertical-tabs/pddljdmihkpdfpkgmbhdomeeifpklgnm), I have so many tabs and so little space :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINE 1000

void countLines(){
    char* line = calloc(LINE, sizeof(char));
    if (line == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to alloc memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int emptyLines = 0;
    int totalLines = 0;
    int totalComments = 0;
    FILE *input = fopen("student.java", "r");
    while (fgets(line, LINE, input) != NULL) {
        int i;
        char *delimiters = " .,\n\t";
        char *token = strtok(line, delimiters);
        for (i = 0; line[i]; i++) {
            if (line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != ' ') {
                emptyLines++;
                break;
            }
        } // counts all the lines that aren't empty
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(token, "/**") == 0) {
                totalComments++;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        } // counts the total amount of comments
        totalLines++; // counts the total amount of lines
    }
    printf("There are %d total lines, %d lines of code and %d comments in the file\n", totalLines, emptyLines, totalComments);
    fclose(input); 
    free(line); 
}


int main(){
    countLines();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Now it works:

Added `token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);`at the end of `strtok while`.

Used `calloc` to alloc `char* line` with control of allocated memory.

Opened just one time the file instead of two.

Changed function `countLines` from `(*int, *int, *int) -> void` to `(void) -> void`.

A tip is to read the manual if you re going to use a function you don't know and be clearer with indentation.

Comment: Curious, why so many space characters in the token list `"   . , \n \t"`?  `" .,\n\t"` certainly is sufficient.

Comment: Could replace `int len = strlen(line); ... for(i = 0; i<len; i++) {` with `for(i = 0; line[i]; i++) {`  to avoid an extra trip down the string `line`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For the first answer, i copied exatly what was in the snippet, now i modified with your tip. Even modified the `for` with your solution, thank you.